# Is the convolution operator with kernel $(1+|x|^2)^\frac{n}{2}$ bounded between Lebesgue spaces?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, distribution-theory, convolution

Suppose we try to define a convolution operator with kernel $K(x) = (1+|x|^2)^\frac{n}{2}$.

For any measurable function $f$ we define

$T[f](x) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x-y) (1+|x|^2)^\frac{n}{2} dy$

It is clear that this a bounded mapping $T : L^1(\mathbb R^n) \rightarrow L^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$. The kernel also happens to be a tempered distribution.

For which exponents $1 \leq p, q \leq \infty$ is this a bounded mapping $T : L^p(\mathbb R^n) \rightarrow L^q(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: For $n=1, f(x)=\frac1 {1+x^{2}}$ $T[f](x)$ does not even exist.

Comment: It does. According to Wolfram Alpha, its value is $2$.